# What is a good way to generate UUIDs of a given length that contain only numbers and letters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

[SecureRandom#urlsafe_base64](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64) contains punctuation characters.

What is a good way to use it to generate a UUID of given length(12) containing only numbers, uppercase and lowercase letters?

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Per the documentation, the only punctuation allowed are `-` and `_`: `The result may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, “-” and “_”. “=” is also used if padding is true.` By stripping those, you can't guarantee that the strings remain UUIDs because they could collide with other similar strings that had the same punctuation in different positions or that differed only by `-` and `_`.

Comment: Maybe but the odds are still 1:12^56 that that would happen. Very long odds.

Comment: How did you get 1:12^56? I got 1:62^12.

Comment: Yes, I think you got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64.gsub(/\W/, '')[0..11]
#=> "x7lADtl95FUH"
```

Comment: This reduces the change that the UUIDs remain as unique as they should be. See my note above.